# Why does a program built with VS 2019 require admin rights to debug

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, administrator

I have a VS 2019 solution that has several utility programs. I can debug all of them except one, which I'll call program XXX. Trying to debug XXX displays the following error message:

'Unable to start program XXX.exe. Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process. To debug this process, Visual Studio must be run as an administrator.'

I've compared the property pages for the debuggable programs against XXX, I cannot discern a difference.

I have .manifest files for all the utility programs, with: `requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"`

All of these utilities read and write to the same set of folders, so I don't think that's the issue.

XXX does not use any references that aren't used by the other utilities.

This has been an issue with VS2016 also.

Is there something in the code that I should be aware of that requires admin rights?

**Additional question**: is there documentation about WHY a program requires admin rights to be debugged?

Comment: Does XXX prompt for elevation if you run it outside VS, for example double-click the .exe in Explorer?

Comment: No, it runs for everyone w/o elevated permissions. - thanks for following up on this question!

Comment: It's going to be hard to guess what's going on without more context and details. Generic advice would be to start removing parts from the offending utility until either the problem goes away and you figure out which part was responsible for it, or else it becomes small enough for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to post here.

Comment: Fair enough. I was hoping that was not going to be the answer, I'll start hacking it up until it debugs.